# Typing a function with 1 function parameter depending on another with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to achieve 2 things:

- make 2 function parameters dependent (done)
- use both parameters inside a function (failed)

My example a bit tricky, I tried simplifying the code from our production into a workable demo:

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CyYbiOXZRTzJVBqUy6aDQ3yoBHBeyYpzkXGmYmWhcoBBvYtJAGmcpNvcqzdS0J47bldom17+otmixWAAzKioBCuxR9mbCYvcEioWiSADWEBAyG7XHrS0g4hOAAoS+39WJtMI9oQB2hItoXW8oGBsRkINp7QaVsJtgBKVOVa1j7d4KRbvV4VY-u5Im2Xw32qS5D1edAsAAxYVgg10gK7PwAHpkKgAAJZASSgQQoGsQhZxwgALRBJFUI5oDJPBpwAfiZVCoAAdSI5IoAASQvQhxEkGCd0gDAACJWwEvYOJLSAEGI4g0kjNoSUQVRVCgAAjaBZXsXCBIFa9omqBEBKgNBVBAei0N4vAVlbbZ9iI5A1HsYUoCE41lXtAz5OAIj-EIdAjJAKBDzgCAwGASQtKvNkomjWgBNMUz2MXecqCgWyADcIC-ZB0q-AT4LQESoGEABlfZCBAMKizy1BtA+at7V9aBKA9O1lwagyfI0kjJFIgKL30ZTVAgaw4pQtDuyED9f0iQThNEqASR8y5cqPVADNw1SoAAeQAOQAGQATS2gAxQr9p0TgnOa1zWvVCBYqZKqVkvVlEISVhULQxjNvaABpEqYBKzgAA1zrlYROAAESgD7mDwPt13WT48DKepgzRGTMyi7M7CfWH4cR6sUdwNGUe0yK8QJPJcbh1AEdbInkxIUmIqjbHaFx5gPqgI7CAUyQAa4EHODByHodQzm0M8nr2AteahGnSRuwo0x2MuHrUGQcDFKwuwcOQKBFWgcKXqFfFcjsdzEE8pdP0ifwXOsPHaaNT0GboBhmZNsxhRxoA)

If you open a playground, you'll see `action[productType];` highlighted with an error, because **action** type is reduced to a union `Type 'ExecutorTypes[T]' cannot be used to index type 'RegularExecutorValue | CustomExecutorValue'`, which in my case is not something I want. I want it to to be strongly typed based

```
type Action = 'create' | 'update';

type ExecutorTypes = {
    regular: ProductType.consumed | ProductType.returned;
    custom: ProductType.consumed;
}

enum ProductType {
    returned = 'returned',
    consumed = 'consumed',
}

type RegularExecutorValue = Record<ExecutorTypes['regular'], string>;
const regularExecutor: Record<Action, RegularExecutorValue> = {
    create: {
        [ProductType.consumed]: 'one',
        [ProductType.returned]: 'two',
    },
    update: {
        [ProductType.consumed]: 'one',
        [ProductType.returned]: 'two',
    },
}

type CustomExecutorValue = Record<ExecutorTypes['custom'], string>;
const customExecutor: Record<Action, CustomExecutorValue> = {
    create: {
        [ProductType.consumed]: 'one',
    },
    update: {
        [ProductType.consumed]: 'one',
    },
}

const executors = {
    regular: regularExecutor,
    custom: customExecutor,
};


function run<T extends keyof ExecutorTypes>(executorType: T, actionType: Action, productType: ExecutorTypes[T]) {
    const executor = executors[executorType];
    const action = executor[actionType];

    // How to make this line work?
    // When I pass executorType="custom", I expect that ProductType will be typed to "ProductType.consumed" only
    // executor[custom] should return "customExecutor" with can only accepts "ProductType.consumed".
    // If you hover over "action", TS says "const action: RegularExecutorValue | CustomExecutorValue" and this is a problem.
    // for executorType="custom", I want "action" to be ONLY OF TYPE "CustomExecutorValue".
    action[productType];
}

/// WORKS AS EXPECTED ///
run('regular', 'create', ProductType.consumed)
run('regular', 'create', ProductType.returned)
run('custom', 'update', ProductType.consumed)

/// Fails AS EXPECTED ///
// this typing works fine. It is not allowed to use "ProductType.returned" with ExecutorType custom
run('custom', 'update', ProductType.returned)
```

Comment: Worst part is when you post a question on Stackoverflow and find yourself and answer in 1 hour...

Comment: No, that's great! Post the answer so others can benefit from it!